# Как сделать что б 2 цикла работали одновременно Python

Tags: python, циклы, for

Есть задача, при которой мне необходимо 2 цикла как-бы "поместить" в 1. Работаю с этим кодом:

```
for i in range(1, pages_count + 1):
    print('Check 1')
    for n in steam_skin:
        print('Check 2')
        for key in steam_keys:
        * тело цикла *
```

В теле цикла я одновременно использую и **n**, и **key**. steam_skin - словарь, steam_keys - масив. Принты добавил для наглядности. Нужно получать результат в консоль такого вида:

```
Check 1
Check 2
Check 1
Check 2
* и так далее *
```

но вместо этого получаю:

```
Check 1
Check 2
Check 2
Check 2
* и так далее *
```

Вроде бы циклы использовал много и по разному, но с этой задачей справится не могу. Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: Посмотрите функцию `zip`.

Comment: посмотрите https://python-scripts.com/threading

Comment: @Михаил Муругов спасибо, помогло

Comment: @Михаил Муругов P.S. запустил скрипт и обнаружил, что теперь почему-то не изменяется параметр n. То есть в консоль выводятся одни и те же значения. При чём key меняется 10 раз, после чего следует точно такой же вывод

Answer (score 0):

Давайте подумаем. 1-й for выполняется, и идёт ко 2-му for, так что нужно делать возврат, для этого можем использовать функцию:

```py
def ch_func():
    for i in range(1, pages_count + 1):
        print('Check 1')
        for n in steam_skin:
            print('Check 2')
            for key in steam_keys:
            #....
            ch_func()
```

Код не тестил, но по логике всё должно работать. Если что, я старался:D